# Using nested intervals to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding this proof from the book "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbot. The problematic part is on page 29 of the book, which is available on [google books](https://books.google.de/books?id=p1t1CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=abbott+understanding+analysis+uncountable+reals&source=bl&ots=DTBrHMuRqG&sig=8-ViWe5YSFMN26ZNCPSiCzVC4d8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=abbott%20understanding%20analysis%20uncountable%20reals&f=false).

Assuming that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, it can be represented as a sequence of numbers:

$\mathbb{R}_s = \{ x_1, x_2, x_3, ... \}$

The idea of the proof is to use [nested interval theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) to show that there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that is not an element of the sequence $\mathbb{R}_s$. This would mean that no such sequence of real number exists.

The proof goes on to construct *finite* and *nested* intervals $I$ such that:

(1) $x_{n} \notin I_n$ and

(2) $I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n$.

It is assumed that $\mathbb{R}_s$ contains all real numbers. Since $x_{n} \ne I_n$, it is clear that for the first number we choose

(3) $x_{n0} \notin\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$

However, the proof claims that since $\mathbb{R}_s$ contains *all real numbers*, this leads to $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \emptyset$

This contradicts with the nested interval theorem that states the opposite: $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n \ne \emptyset$

Therefore no such sequence $\mathbb{R}_s$ can be constructed, which means $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

**My questions**

Q1: If all the intervals are *finite*, how can we even use $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$?

Example: Choose $x_3$ for $x_{n0}$ and $\{x_4, x_5, .... x_{n}\}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $I_1$ - following (1) and (2). How can I construct infinitely many nested intervals from a finite $I_1$ following (1) and (2)? There are maximally $n-1$ such nested sub-intervals, if $I_{n+1}$ is constructed from $I_n$ such that the first or the last element of $I_n$ is chosen as $x_{n+1}$.

Q2: This part:

> (3) $x_{n0} \notin\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$
>
> However, the proof claims that since $\mathbb{R}_s$ contains *all real
>   numbers*, this leads to $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \emptyset$

(3) is perfectly clear, but how does that lead to $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \emptyset$? I mean, sure, (3) is valid for *any* $x_{n0} \in \mathbb{R}_s$, but that doesn't break the nested interval theorem. The nested interval theorem states basically that $I_n \ne \emptyset$.

Is this the point? Rules (1) and (2) will enforce a constructuion of such $I_{n}$ that is an empty set, causing the intersection of all intervals to be empty?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, rather than $x_n\ne I_n,$ $(1)$ should read $x_n\notin I_n.$ What would it even mean for a real number to be equal to an interval of real numbers? This may be mistranscribed by you, or it may be a mistake in your text.

---

Second of all, there is the statement "there are maximally $n-1$ nested subintervals, if $I_{n+1}$ is constructed from $I_n$ such that the first or the last element of $I_n$ is chosen as $x_{n+1}.$" I suspect that you're misunderstanding what is meant by "finite" in the sense of intervals. It does *not* mean that the interval has only finitely-many elements. Rather, it means that the interval is *bounded* (or, equivalently, of finite *length*). In particular, each interval in the construction  has the form $[c,d]:=\{x\in\Bbb R:c\le x\text{ and }x\le d\}$ for some $c,d\in\Bbb R$ with $c<d$. I'm not sure how your proof constructs these intervals, but here is one way we can proceed:

> First of all, let $I_1=[x_1+1,x_1+2].$ Note that this is a finite, non-empty, closed interval, and that $x_1\notin I_1.$ Suppose we have a finite, non-empty, closed interval $I_n.$ Then there are a few cases to consider.
>
> - If $x_{n+1}\notin I_n,$ then we simply let $I_{n+1}=I_n$.
> - If $x_{n+1}$ is the least element of $I_n$--meaning that $I_n=[x_{n+1},d]$ for some $d>x_{n+1}$--then we choose some $c$ with $x_{n+1}<c$ and $c<d$--for example, we could use $c=\frac12(x_{n+1}+d)$--and let $I_{n+1}=[c,d].$
> - If $x_{n+1}$ is an element of $I_n,$ but is *not* the least element--meaning that $I_n=[c,d]$ for some $c<x_{n+1}$ and some $d\ge x_{n+1}$--then we choose some $d'$ with $c<d'$ and $d'<x_{n+1}$--for example, $d'=\frac12(c+x_{n+1})$--and let $I_{n+1}=[c,d'].$

You should be able to see/prove that, regardless of which case we have $I_{n+1}$ is a finite, non-empty, closed subinterval of $I_n$ such that $x_{n+1}\notin I_{n+1}.$ Note, however, that there were *many* ways we could have chosen the subinterval! For example, in the first case, we could have chosen *any* (non-empty, closed) subinterval of $I_n$. In the second case, we could have chosen $c$ in many ways--for example, given any $0<t<1,$ we could let $c=tx_{n+1}+(1-t)d.$ Similarly, we could choose $d'$ in many ways in the third case. (It turns out that there are *uncountably-many* ways to choose an appropriate sub-interval, but that isn't important, and is tantamount to what we're trying to prove!) Moreover, the above procedure recursively constructs all of the $I_n$ for us.

---

Finally, there is the statement "(3) is valid for *any* $x_{n_0}\in\Bbb R_s,$ but that doesn't break the nested interval theorem. The nested interval theorem states basically that $I_n\ne\emptyset.$" But this is not so! Rather, the NIT states that if there is a sequence of intervals $I_n$ of real numbers such that (i) each $I_n\ne\emptyset,$ (ii) each $I_n$ is of the form $[c,d]$ for some real $c,d,$ and (iii) $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$ for all $n,$ then we have that $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n:=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\in I_n\text{ for all }n\ge 1\}\ne\emptyset.\tag{$\star$}$$ Note that it is *necessary* that each $I_n$ is non-empty, but the conclusion is $(\star).$ Since our construction meets the criteria for NIT, we can conclude that $(\star)$ holds, and so there is some $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n.$ By assumption, $x\in\Bbb R_s,$ so $x=x_{n_0}$ for some $n_0.$ But by (3), this is impossible: since $x_{n_0}\notin I_{n_0}$ by construction, then $x=x_{n_0}\notin\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$. Thus, we have a contradiction.

Comment: Finite is the wrong term, I see that now. Some things are still not clear to me. The sequence $\mathbb{R}_s$ does not have to be ordered in any way, with respect to values of $x \in \mathbb{R}_s$ - rules (1) and (2) don't tell me how the intervals are constructed. Therefore, even though $I_n$ is bounded, (1) and (2) do not prescribe the form [c,d]:={x∈R:c≤x and x≤d}[c,d]:={x∈R:c≤x and x≤d} for some c,d∈Rc,d∈R with c<dc<d, right?

Comment: Well, "finite" is fine, but when it comes to intervals, "finite" refers to the *length*, not the cardinality. As for the order, remember that $\Bbb R_s$ is supposed to be an indexing of *all the elements of* $\Bbb R$--something like $\{0,-2,\pi,e,\pi-e,\dots\}.$ So, on the one hand, the terms of the sequence aren't necessarily *indexed* in a particular prescribed order, but on the other hand, the set of sequence terms is still ordered in the usual sense (otherwise, we couldn't talk about "intervals" in the first place). Does your proof actually construct the intervals, or just say "construct"?

Comment: It's not my proof, I should have stated that earlier. I've edited the question and added a link to google books, the proof is from a book. The proof doesn't construct intervals. It relies on the rules (1) and (2) to reduce every subsequent nested interval by at least one element.

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't actually construct it, but it gives you a (misleading) graphic to show you the idea, and says that the reader *should verify that it is possible* to construct an interval adhering to rules (1) and (2) at every stage. I say it is misleading, because it seems to suggest that $x_{n+1}$ will always be an element of $I_n,$ which is patently not the case. So, let me ask you a few questions. Does the construction I gave make sense to you? Were you able to verify that it adheres to the rules? Did any part of the construction seem unnecessary?

Comment: @tmaric: Have you had a chance to think about the questions I asked?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think finite in this case is supposed to mean bounded. You can't have finite intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ in terms of the number of points contained in the intervals with the exception of one point intervals.

As for the proof I think it's fairly straightforward. You take an arbitrary closed interval a the start. Let's say $[0,1]$.

At each step you define $I_{n+1}$ to either be $I_n$ if $x_n\not\in I_n$ or assuming $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ you split the interval into thirds $I_{n,1}=[a_n,a_n+(b_n-a_n)/3]$,$I_{n,3}= [a_n+2(b_n-a_n)/3,b_n]$ and choose an $\alpha$ so that $x_n\not\in I_{n,\alpha}$ (you can always choose one of these since the two intervals are disjoint).

These intervals are then nested non-empty and closed thus $\bigcap I_n\neq\emptyset$, thus $\exists x\in\bigcap I_n$. But this $x$ is real and so was enumerated in our original sequence $\mathbb{R}_s$ and thus at some stage $n$ we had $x\not\in I_n$, thus $x\not\in \bigcap I_n$ and we have a contradiction.

Comment: Question: aren't you assuming that every $I$ is a [monotonic sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotonicSequence.html)?

Comment: @tmaric I'm not sure what you mean by every I is monotonic.  I'm ensuring that the intervals are nested. But I have no requirements on the x_i's. They can be in any order they like. I choose which part of the interval to throw away depending on where in the current interval x_i turns out to be.

Comment: @tmaric Partially in response to your other question in comments. In "most"/many cases $I_{n+1}=I_n$. I only need to shrink the interval in case $x_{n+1}\in I_n$. If it turns out $x_{n+1}$ is already not in the interval I don't have to do anything. This will be the case a lot of the time. Don't forget with every shrinking of the interval to avoid **one** $x_n$ we at the same time avoid another uncountably many $x_i$'s, since we throw out a whole subinterval.

Comment: monotonicity: If there is no ordering imposed on $I_n$, then I can choose $I_n = [a_n, b_n] = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}_s :  x > b_n \}$. If I use interval arithmetics on boundaries, I will get $I_{n,1} = {a_n}, I_{n,3} = {b_n}$, regardless of $x_n$. Since they have a single element, that is non-empty, there is no contradiction with the nested interval theorem. Assuming $I_n = [a_n, b_n]$ and splitting that interval based on $a_n$ and $b_n$ arithmetically, expects $I_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}_s : a_n \le x \le b_n \}$, does it not?

Comment: @tmaric $I_n$ is some non empty closed interval (with a non-empty interior, I don't point this out in the answer since that seemed obvious). As such $I_n=[a_n,b_n]=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\;a_n\leq x\leq b_n\}$. I don't understand where you are getting $[a_n,b_n]=\{x\in\mathbb{R}_S:\;x>b_n\}$. What does $\mathbb{R}_S$ have to do with the interval?

Comment: The idea is to apply nested intervals on $\mathbb{R}_s$, not on $\mathbb{R}$. In $\mathbb{R}_s$, the numbers are counted, which means that by nesting the interval following (1) and (2), we will eventually reach a set with just one element. Expecting to build the next nested interval from this one using (1) and (2), makes us drop the final element and get $I_n = \emptyset$, that results in $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \emptyset$. _Then_ we may say that $\mathbb{R}_s$ contains all elements of $\mathbb{R}$, and for $\mathbb{R}$ we know that the nested intervval theorem is valid - a contradiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30346/discussion-between-drf-and-tmaric).

Answer (score 1):

For Q2:

We have shown that for all $n0$, $x_{n0}\notin \cap_{n\geq 1}I_n$. That is, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_s$, $x\notin \cap_{n\geq 1}I_n$. Since we assume $\mathbb{R}_s=\mathbb{R}$ this implies $\cap_{n\geq 1}I_n=\emptyset$

For Q1:

Since we assume $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, we can consider a sequence $(x_n)_n$, with $x_1>1$ which includes all the real numbers. Let's construct the sets $I_n$ recursively like this: $I_1=[0,1]$ (then $x_1\notin I_1$), and given $I_n$, let 
\begin{equation*}
I_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
I_n &\text{if $x_{n+1}\notin I_n$}\\
[\min I_n,(\min I_n+x_n)/2]\subset I_n &\text{if $x_{n+1}\in (\min I_n,\max I_n]$}\\
[(\min I_n+\max I_n)/2,(\max I_n)]\subset I_n &\text{if $x_{n+1}= \min I_n$}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation*}

This sequence will be such that conditions (1) and (2) are verified.

Comment: Q1: If $I_1 = I_2$ is there $x \in I_1$ such that $x \notin I_2$? Rules (1) and (2) force me to pick an element $x_{n+1}$ from $I_n$ such that $x_{n+1} \notin I_{n+1}$ which is equivalent to $x_n \notin I_n$ which is rule (1). Each time a new interval $I_{n+1}$ is constructed, an element $x_{n+1}$ from $I_n$ is picked such that $x_{n+1} \notin I_{n+1}$. Maybe I have not been clear enough on that..

Comment: I don't see why rules (1) and (2) force you to pick an element $x_{n+1}\in I_n$. Let $I_1=[0,1]=I_2$, and $x_1=3,x_2=2$. They verify (1) and (2), to my understanding. Besides, if you were forced to pick $x_{n+1}\in I_n$ then $x_2\in I_1, x_3\in I_2\subseteq I_1,...$. This implies your sequence is included in $I_1\cup \{x_1\}$ so it could not cover $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It's my fault, I should have added this part to the question. "Let $I_1$ be a closed interval that does not contain $x_1$ . Next, let $I_2$ be a closed interval, contained in $I_1$ , which does not contain $x_2$ ....".

Comment: What you mention is equivalent to conditions (1) and (2), I think. I don't see why this implies $x_{n+1}\in I_n$.

Comment: cover $\mathbb{R}$ : I don't understand what should cover $\mathbb{R}$, the [nested interval theorem](http://personal.bgsu.edu/~carother/cantor/Nested.html) doesn't assume that $I_n$ or $\cup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ cover $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: My apologies. It is the sequence $(x_n)_n$ which "covers" (more precisely, includes every term in) $\mathbb{R}$. Since we assume $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, one such a sequence exists.