# Nested Interval Property for Real Indices

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

The nested interval property states:

For each $n \in \mathbf{N}$, assume we are given a closed interval $I_n = [a_n, b_n] = \{x \in \mathbf{R} : a_n \leq x \leq b_n\}$. Assume also that each $I_n$ contains $I_{n+1}$. Then, the resulting sequence of closed intervals: $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \supseteq I_4 \supseteq \dots$ has a nonempty intersection. (Abbot, Understanding Analysis)

I understand the proof of this statement. However, I was wondering if the proof is limited to $n \in \mathbf{N}$? Can the indices for the intervals instead be real, that is $n \in \mathbf{R}$?

The reason I ask this is because I've seen a proof that the real numbers are uncountable that relies on the nested interval property (see [Using nested intervals to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481294/using-nested-intervals-to-prove-that-mathbbr-is-not-countable)). While I understand this proof, I do not see how the countability of the reals plays a role in the contradiction that is reached (i.e. I do not see how assuming the reals are uncountable would allow us to avoid the contradiction -- unless the nested interval property does not work with real indices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean $\supseteq$ and not $\subseteq$, since otherwise $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n = I_1$.

Assuming you mean $\supseteq$, if you had $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$, then the hypothesis would presumably be that $I_r \supseteq I_s$ for all $r<s$. In this case, you'd have
$$\bigcap_{x \in \mathbb{R}} I_x ~=~ \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n$$
since $I_x \supseteq I_{\mathrm{max}\{1, \lceil x \rceil\}}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So this property for $\mathbb{N}$-indexed intervals implies the same property for $\mathbb{R}$-indexed intervals.

Comment: Yes, that was my bad with the subset symbols, thank you! So, with that in mind, would you happen to know why (specifically) the reals being countable leads to a contradiction in the proof attached?

Comment: @dts: I'm not sure I can explain succinctly in a comment, but the question you linked to (and its answers) contain a proof, as far as I can tell. The idea is, if $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, you can construct a nested sequence of intervals with empty intersection—this is a contradiction. It doesn't have to do with the indexing of the intervals; rather, it has to do with the fact that a countable sequence of intervals violating the nested interval property can be constructed in the first place.

Comment: So, if we instead assumed the reals are uncountable (as they are), what would change? Wouldn't we still be able to construct a nested sequence of intervals with empty intersection? Is this not a contradiction because we have an uncountable sequence of intervals?

Comment: @dts: No, you wouldn't be able to do that. (If you could, then that would contradict the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable!) See e.g. Nate River's answer to that question for how the sequence is constructed when you assume $\mathbb{R}$ is countable; a construction like that just doesn't work without the assumption of countability.